# Git subtree - a subdirectory in the project that I want to receive changes from upstream

Tags: git, merge, subtree

I have what I thought was a pretty standard use case for git subtree, but perhaps I'm missing something. I've got a a local repo with a sub directory containing code. That code is just a local copy (no git config) of an older version of an upstream project. What I'm aiming to do is merge a tag from the upstream remote repo into this sub directory and make it a subtree. When trying to run the follow commands I receive:

```
git subtree pull --prefix=subdir remote_repo remote_tag --squash
fatal: ambiguous argument '$hash^0': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
could not rev-parse split hash $hash from commit $hash
Can't squash-merge: '$prefix' was never added.
```

But when I try to add it:

```
git subtree add --prefix subdir remote_repo remote_tag
prefix $prefix already exists.
```

Is this a use case for the "split" option? I'm honestly not entirely sure what that does, but any help would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by adding the remote_repo as a remote and doing a fetch on the tags before doing the pull.

git remote add upstream $remote_repo
git fetch --tags upstream

Comment: This fixed the problem because the hash is the hash of an annotated tag, which was written to the `git-subtree-split` trailer by pre 2.32 Git versions. Note that Git 2.39 and later would automatically fetch the needed tag so your `git subtree pull` invocation would work out-of-the-box.

Comment: See https://github.com/git/git/commit/1762382ab19dd6d5d84dd32e35e25c2b55b651f0 and more precisely https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d330673d4fa9e0bea91092abb657606f4325e7e

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `git subtree` error message with be clearer with With Git 2.39 (Q4 2022):

See [commit 1762382](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1762382ab19dd6d5d84dd32e35e25c2b55b651f0), [commit 0d33067](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d330673d4fa9e0bea91092abb657606f4325e7e), [commit f10d31c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f10d31cf2d41fb892fbda1fb2b77dd518418c1a1), [commit 7990142](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7990142eb1b6fdd60e87f63f003bc593fc105260), [commit 34ab458](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34ab458cb1df13ca400c10bbc4ff69c75a4e217e), [commit 5626a9e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5626a9e2a93e4dd0ce13005a7fc1d74c2c3e4fd2), [commit 2e94339](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e94339fdc3122fd2f92e865105523bc3866a65f), [commit a50fcc1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a50fcc13dda245b39e63a2052107456e0b7e85f7), [commit 455f0ad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/455f0adf5709e24712bff725005ff1a59508a054) (21 Oct 2022) by [Philippe Blain (`phil-blain`)](https://github.com/phil-blain).
<sup>(Merged by [Taylor Blau -- `ttaylorr` --](https://github.com/ttaylorr) in [commit a23e0b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a23e0b69e2d25a893e187d86719de0b12b324579), 30 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a50fcc13dda245b39e63a2052107456e0b7e85f7): use '`git rev-parse --verify [--quiet]`' for better error messages
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philippe Blain</sup>

> There are three occurences of '[`git rev-parse <rev>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a50fcc13dda245b39e63a2052107456e0b7e85f7/Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse))</sup> in '`git-subtree.sh`' where the command expects a revision and the script dies or exits if the revision can't be found.
> In that case, the error message from '`git rev-parse`' is:
>
> ```
> $ git rev-parse <bad rev>
> <bad rev>
> fatal: ambiguous argument '<bad rev>': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
> Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
> 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
> ```
>
> This is a little confusing to the user, since this error message is outputed by `git subtree`.
>
> At these points in the script, we know that we are looking for a single revision, so be explicit by using '`--verify`', resulting in a little better error message:
>
> ```
> $ git rev-parse --verify <bad rev>
> fatal: Needed a single revision
> ```
>
> In the two occurrences where we 'die' if '`git rev-parse`' fails, `git subtree` outputs "`could not rev-parse split hash $b from commit $sq`", so we actually do not need the supplementary error message from '`git rev-parse`'; add '`--quiet`' to silence it.
>
> In the third occurrence, we '`exit`', so keep the error message from '`git rev-parse`'.
> Note that this message is still sub-optimal since it can be understood to mean that '`git rev-parse`' did not receive a single revision as argument, which is not the case here: the command did receive a single revision, but the revision is not resolvable to an available object.
>
> The alternative would be to use '`--`' after the revision, as suggested by the first error message, resulting in a clearer error message:
>
> ```
> $ git rev-parse <bad rev> --
> fatal: bad revision '<bad rev>'
> ```
>
> Unfortunately we can't use that syntax because in the more common case of the revision resolving to a known object, the command outputs the object's hash, a newline, and the dashdash, which breaks the git subtree script.